# Pivoting data in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe:

```
dat<- data.frame(date = c("2015-01-01","2015-01-01","2015-01-01", "2015-01-01","2015-02-02","2015-02-02","2015-02-02","2015-02-02","2015-02-02"), val= c(10,20,30,50,300,100,200,200,400), type= c("A","A","B","C","A","A","B","C","C") )
dat

       date val type
1 2015-01-01  10    A
2 2015-01-01  20    A
3 2015-01-01  30    B
4 2015-01-01  50    C
5 2015-02-02 300    A
6 2015-02-02 100    A
7 2015-02-02 200    B
8 2015-02-02 200    C
9 2015-02-02 400    C
```

and I would like to have one row for each day with averages by type so the output would be:

```
Date           A     B     C
2015-01-01    15     30    50
2015-02-02    200     200   300
```

additionally how would I get the counts so the results are:

```
Date           A     B     C
2015-01-01    2      1     1
2015-02-02    2      1     2
```

Comment: In R-speak this is called "aggregation". The `aggregate` function is very helpful for this.

Answer (score 9):

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(data = dat, formula = date ~ type, fun.aggregate = mean, value.var = "val")

#         date   A   B   C
# 1 2015-01-01  15  30  50
# 2 2015-02-02 200 200 300
```

With `dcast`, the LHS of the formula defines rows, the RHS defines columns, the `value.var` is the name of the column that becomes values, and the `fun.aggregate` is how those values are computed. The default `fun.aggregate` is `length`, i.e., the number of values. You asked for the average, so we use `mean`. You could also do `min`, `max`, `sd`, `IQR`, or any function that takes a vector and returns a single value.

Comment: Nice. Just about to post the same thing.

Comment: Hi @Gregor thank you. What if I wanted the count of rows instead of mean?  Thank you!

Comment: @user3022875  But, you showed the expected output as this.  By default, you will get the length (if you don't specify any function)

Comment: I am just asking how would I get the count as well.

Comment: @user3022875: `fun.aggregate = length`

Answer (score 6):

You may also use `table` for the updated question

```
  table(dat[c(1,3)])
  #            type
  #date       A B C
  #2015-01-01 2 1 1
  #2015-02-02 2 1 2
```

For the first question, I think @Gregor's solution is the best (so far), a possible option with `dplyr/tidyr` would be

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(tidyr)
 dat %>%
    group_by(date,type) %>%
    summarise(val=mean(val)) %>% 
    spread(type, val)
```

Or a `base R` option would be (`nchar=50` and the `dcast(..` `nchar=44`.  So not so bad :-))

```
  with(dat, tapply(val, list(date, type), FUN=mean))
  #            A   B   C
  #2015-01-01  15  30  50
  #2015-02-02 200 200 300
```

Comment: I like the `tapply` one, probably the best base R solution for this task.

Comment: I agree with @DavidArenburg, great job. I especially like `table` for the simple row counting.

Comment: Thank you both for the generous comments

Answer (score 3):

Personally I would go with Gregor's solution using `reshape2`. But for the sake of completeness I'll include a base R solution.

```
agg <- with(dat, aggregate(val, by = list(date = date, type = type), FUN = mean))

out <- reshape(agg, timevar = "type", idvar = "date", direction = "wide")

out
#         date x.A x.B x.C
# 1 2015-01-01  15  30  50
# 2 2015-02-02 200 200 300
```

If you want to get rid of the `x.` on the column names, you can remove it with `gsub`.

```
colnames(out) <- gsub("^x\\.", "", colnames(out))
```

To get the counts of rows, replace `FUN = mean` with `FUN = length` in the call to `aggregate`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table v1.9.5` (current devel), we can do:

```
require(data.table) ## v1.9.5+
dcast(setDT(dat), date ~ type, fun = list(mean, length), value.var="val")
#          date A_mean_val B_mean_val C_mean_val A_length_val B_length_val C_length_val
# 1: 2015-01-01         15         30         50            2            1            1
# 2: 2015-02-02        200        200        300            2            1            2
```

Installation instructions [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).

Answer (score 1):

I'll add the [`pivot_wider`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html) solution, which is meant to replace earlier `tidyverse` options, and which is

Using `pivot_wider` with the `values_fn` option, we can do the following:

```r
library(tidyr) # At least 1.0.0

dat %>% pivot_wider(names_from = type, values_from = val, values_fn = list(val = mean))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   date           A     B     C
#>   <fct>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 2015-01-01    15    30    50
#> 2 2015-02-02   200   200   300
```

and

```
dat %>% pivot_wider(names_from = type, values_from = val, values_fn = list(val = length))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   date           A     B     C
#>   <fct>      <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 2015-01-01     2     1     1
#> 2 2015-02-02     2     1     2
```

Of course, if we want to get fancy, we can do both at once:

```
library(purrr)
library(rlang)

map(quos(mean, length), 
    ~pivot_wider(dat, names_from = type, values_from = val, values_fn = list(val = eval_tidy(.))))
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   date           A     B     C
#>   <fct>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 2015-01-01    15    30    50
#> 2 2015-02-02   200   200   300
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   date           A     B     C
#>   <fct>      <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 2015-01-01     2     1     1
#> 2 2015-02-02     2     1     2
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Note that if you're concerned about speed, [it may be worth updating to the dev version of tidyr](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/775).