# Pivoting data in R with duplicate rows

Tags: r, reshape, tidyr

Trying to do a simple pivot in R, much like you would in SQL.

I understand this question has been asked however I am having trouble with duplicate rows.

[Pivoting data in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30198173/pivoting-data-in-r)

Currently the data is in this format (characters are just placeholders for ease of viewing. The actual data is numerical):

```
V1 V2 V3 V4
A  B  C  Sales
D  E  F  Sales
G  H  I  Technical
J  K  L  Technical
```

And it needs to be transformed into this format:

```
Variable Sales Technical
V1       A     G
V1       D     J
V2       B     H
V2       E     K
V3       C     I
V3       F     L
```

I've tried both reshape and tidyr packages and they either aggregate the data in the case of reshape or throw errors for duplicate row identifiers in the case of tidyr.

I don't care about duplicate row identifiers, infact it's necessary to identify them as factors for analysis.

Am I going about this the wrong way? Are these the correct packages to be using or can anyone suggest another method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope this will work:

```
df %>% gather(Variable, Value, V1:V3) %>%
    group_by(V4, Variable) %>%
    mutate(g = row_number()) %>%
    spread(V4, Value) %>% ungroup() %>%
    select(-g)

# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#   Variable Sales Technical
# *    <chr> <chr>     <chr>
# 1       V1     A         G
# 2       V1     D         J
# 3       V2     B         H
# 4       V2     E         K
# 5       V3     C         I
# 6       V3     F         L
```

Comment: Fantastic that worked a treat!! Excellent, thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

Another option is `melt/dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(df1), id.var = 'V4'), variable + rowid(V4) ~
                V4, value.var = 'value')[, V4 := NULL][]
#   variable Sales Technical
#1:       V1     A         G
#2:       V1     D         J
#3:       V2     B         H
#4:       V2     E         K
#5:       V3     C         I
#6:       V3     F         L
```